# Spades - mirror variant

Tags: variants, spades

In Spades, the variant **"Spades mirror"** means that each player must bid exactly the number of Spades cards she got.

This variant remove the bidding phase of the game and leaves only the playing.  Sums of bids are always 13 and players have knowledge of how many spades each player poses.

My question is, **what are the main differences in the game play** from the regular Spades, I mean how my strategy should change?

Comment: One could argue that your strategy shouldn't change at all. Once the bid is in (regardless of the variant), the goal is to get your bid.

Comment: You have more information (spades# of each player) so:  if someone played X tricks of spades where X is her bid, then you know she is void in spades.  If someone plays Y tricks of non spades where Y = 13-bid, then you know that player is void in all suit but spades.

Comment: Total bids are always 13, thus getting a sandbag will set your opponents.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good variant as you can have a really bad hand with a couple of low spades and be forced to bid when it is near impossible to get that.

Comment: indeed this variant has much more luck involve, however it is popular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, there are two differences from play of a regular round:

1. Players know the number of spades each player holds.  You know a player is void in spades after she plays X spades, where X is her bid. It can help in deciding whether to lead spades.
2. Table bid is 13.  Each round is an "Over" round: an extra bag means the opponents' contract is set.